# Caching dynamic images rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, amazon-s3

In my web app each user will be having a profile image those images are stored in Amazon s3. If the user signs in i need to show that image and that will stay in the side bar in all the pages he enters. Once he signs in is there anyway i can cache the image so that i no need to get back from Amazon s3 every time ? when he again updates the image i need to clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard [Http Caching](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) for this.

You should set the [`Cache-Control`](http://keakaj.com/wisdom/2007/07/27/cache-control-header-for-amazon-s3/) and/or [`expires`](http://htmlcssjavascript.com/web/setting-far-future-expires-headers-for-images-in-amazon-s3/) headers depending on your needs.

All the major S3 clients support setting these headers or you can set using the S3 API's or SDKs/Libraries etc.

In order to re-download the image if it has changed, you can add a querystring to the url.
eg

```
http://mypath/myfile.ext?v=1
http://mypath/myfile.ext?v=2
```